# Documents appear in approve/reject view with document sets when content approval turned on

Tags: document-set, content-approval

I sense this is a "feature".  I am in a SharePoint online environment.  I have document sets turned on, and I have a document set created.  When I turn content approval on, in the approve/reject view, the documents appear in the view at the same level as the document set.  Example:
Document set 1
File 1
File 2

If you open the document set, the files appear as they should.

I found a workaround, but I wanted to check with the collective, if others had experienced this as well.

Comment: great use case! pls post the workaround when appropriate!

Comment: Hi Vamsi,  I turned off Content Approval.  Then Documents and Document Sets behaved.  I created a group that has restricted read (restricted contribute would work too) and I have one view.  The owner of the list can create a personal view if needed.
I created a person/group field and to the view, and filtered based on that Person/Group field = [ME] and then when the members log in, they only see the document sets that they have been assigned.